# Something like Explorer's icon grid view in a Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I am making a Python gui project that needs to duplicate the look of a Windows gui environment (ie Explorer).  I have my own custom icons to draw but they should be selectable by the same methods as usual; click, ctrl-click, drag box etc.  Are any of the gui toolkits going to help with this or will I have to implement it all myself.  If there aren't any tools to help with this advice would be greatly appreciated.

*edit* I am not trying to recreate explorer, that would be madness.  I simply want to be able to take icons and lay them out in a scrollable window.  Any number of them may be selected at once.  It would be great if there was something that could select/deselect them in the same (appearing at least) way that Windows does.  Then all I would need is a list of all the selected icons.

Comment: Appearance on the Daily WTF in 3...2...1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has extensions for accessing the Win32 API, but good luck trying to re-write explorer in *that* by yourself. Your best bet is to use a toolkit like [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/gallery-windowsxp.html), but you'll still have to write the vast majority of the application from scratch.

Is there any way you can re-use explorer itself in your project?

---

Updated for edited question:

[GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) has an [icon grid widget](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkIconView.html) that you could use. See a reference for [PyGTK+](http://www.pygtk.org/): [`gtk.IconView`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkiconview.html)

Comment: Thanks, found what I was looking for.  It is hard to google for stuff when you don't know the name.

Answer (score 2):

In wxPython there's a plethora of ready-made list and tree controls (CustomTreeCtrl, TreeListCtrl, and others), a mixture of which you can use to create a simple explorer in minutes. The wxPython demo even has a few relevant examples (see the demo of MVCTree).

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're serious and suggest that you check out the many wonderful [GUI libraries](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) available for Python.